# connecting a MPU6050 and sabertooth 2x12 to a single Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

so im using the sabertooth speed controller to control the two motors on my lawn mower and im trying to use the MPU6050 to keep the lawn mower straight. The problem im facing is that im trying to use the sabertooth and the MPU6050 on a single Arduino and the sabertooth uses the baud rate of 9600 but the MPU6050 uses 115200 and im trying to use a single .ino file to control everything. I want to receive the data from the MPU6050 and based of that make a program to move the motor so that the mower will go in a straight line and such.

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: I know only of MPU6050 boards, that use I2C. Are you sure your MPU is using Serial (UART)?